# Could not find a storyboard named

Tags: xcode5

I am trying to create my first app in xcode 5. I am following the instructions at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/FirstTutorial.html to add a story board.

As soon as I try to run after adding a view controller, I get the following:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalid Argumentxception', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'Main' in bundle 'NSBundle'

My storyboard is named Main. And it is listed as the Main interface. And I have tried deleting the project and recreating it from scratch... many times.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the story board is not activated as your main storyboard.

Have you completed the next section of the tutorial?

-> "To set the storyboard as the app’s main interface"
...
->  "5: "Select your storyboard, Main.storyboard."